# how can I wait for a google distance call to return my results before looping the next iteration

Tags: javascript

I have two Arrays (gOriginsArray, gDestinationsArray) which are Array of Arrays and I am storing 10 addresses in each array and I have close to 300 origins addresses and 300 destinations address stored in a sets of 10 entries. My gOriginsArray has 300 identical elements.
I am running a loop and sending 10 addresses from both array to calculate the distance but my loop carries on before I get result from DistanceMatrixService and I get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error as well.

I want to find the distance of all 300 addresses and then run LoadBookingsArray(Records) function.

```js
for (var k = 0; k < gDestinationsArray.length; k++) {
  var DistanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  DistanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: gOriginsArray[k],
    destinations: gDestinationsArray[k],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      for (var l = 0; l < results.length; l++) {
        gDistanceArray.push(results[l].distance.text);
      }
    } else if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('OVER_QUERY_LIMIT');
      }, 10000);
    } else {
      console.log(status);
      gDistanceArray.push('');
    }
  });

}
LoadBookingsArray(Records);
```

[image]

My Updated version with async/await

```js
async function RunBookings() {
    for (var k = 0; k < gDestinationsArray.length; k++) {        
        let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {            
            var DistanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            DistanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: gOriginsArray[k],
                destinations: gDestinationsArray[k],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var results = response.rows[0].elements; 
                    for (var l = 0; l < results.length; l++) {
                        gDistanceArray.push(results[l].distance.text);
                    }
                    resolve('Good promise');
                } else if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    console.log('OVER_QUERY_LIMIT');
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(status);
                    reject(Error("Bad promise"));
                } else {
                    console.log('BAD');
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(status);
                    reject(new Error("Bad promise"));
                }
            });
        });
        let result = await promise;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the issue.

I have to wait for 10 Seconds before I send the next request.

The Google Maps Distance Matrix API has the following limits in place (Users of the standard API): 2,500 free elements per day. 100 elements per query. 100 elements per 10 seconds.Jan 18, 2016

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're iterating over an asynchronous operation - DistanceService.getDistanceMatrix.
Validate that it returns a Promise and refactor your code to handle Promises with async/await by wrapping your gDestinationsArray loop within an async function and await for DistanceService.getDistanceMatrix to finish before moving to the next iteration.

Comment: Hi graumanoz, Sorry for the late reply. I treid async/await as well but I am still getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in the second iteration.

Comment: @KarimAli Are you sure that `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error is not an indication that you're making too many calls within a 24 hour period (or 30 day or whatever your subscription entitles you to)? I had seen this error in the past - and that was the reason.

Comment: HI All, I have found the issue. I have to wait for 10 Seconds before I send the next request.The Google Maps Distance Matrix API has the following limits in place (Users of the standard API): 2,500 free elements per day. 100 elements per query. 100 elements per 10 seconds.Jan 18, 2016